# Checking $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\frac {d^2}{dx^2}e^{-ax^2}dx $

Tags: integration

I just did this, but I'd appreciate some rather expert eyes to see if there are any mistakes: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}\frac {d^2}{dx^2}e^{-ax^2}dx = I_1 $$ $$ \frac {d^2}{dx^2}e^{-ax^2}= 2a(2ax^2-1) e^{-ax^2} $$ $$ I_1= 2a \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(2ax^2-1) e^{-2ax^2} $$ using gamma function $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-2ax}dx=\left( \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2(2a)^{3/2}}  \right)$$ $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2ax^2}dx=\left(\frac{\pi^{1/2}}{(2a)^{1/2}} \right) $$ 
thus $$ I_1= 2a \left[2a\left( \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2(2a)^{3/2}}  \right)- \left(\frac{\pi^{1/2}}{(2a)^{1/2}} \right) \right]$$

Is this correct?

Comment: With a huge simplification at the end, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, but note that you can simplify this to 
\begin{align}
2a\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}\left( \frac{2a}{2\cdot 2a}-1\right)=-\sqrt{\frac{ \pi a}{2}}.
\end{align}

For another time, you can check it with Wolfram Alpha or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

By integration by parts, the substitution $x=\frac{z}{\sqrt{a}}$ and the identity $\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{\beta-1}e^{-z}\,dz=\Gamma(\beta)$
$$ I_1 = -\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{d}{dx}e^{-ax^2}\right)^2\,dx=\color{red}{-\sqrt{\frac{\pi a}{2}}}. $$